# Should there be a tag for top level domains for web-based questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

In https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/1599/70 I provided a suggestion on how to use a particular on-line product. It turns out that although this is a global enterprise, particular features depend upon where you log-in. That is a significant contextual variable that needs to be attached to questions (and answers).

Is the best way to distinguish between findmypast.com and findmypast.co.uk to duplicate the full tag, or to add com, comau, comca, and couk as new tags that could be used with the existing findmypast and also ancestry?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but by using wildcards in the search bar we can see that, after 1,173 questions:

- Only 2 have been [tagged `[findmypast*]`](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/findmypast.co.uk+or+findmypast) with both having [findmypast](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/findmypast) and [findmypast.co.uk](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/findmypast.co.uk) tags
- 37 have been [tagged `[ancestry*]`](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancestry*) but these have all been tagged [ancestry.com](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancestry.com)

I think that:

- [ancestry.com](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancestry.com) is working fine
- [findmypast.co.uk](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/findmypast.co.uk) should be made a synonym of [findmypast](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/findmypast) - with a note made in its tag wiki that the actual findmypast domain name used should be written into the body of the question (no need for a separate tag)

Answer (score -1):

I think Ancestry.com, Ancestry.ca, Findmypast.com, Findmypast.co.uk etc should all be separate tags (especially the last two as the interface is so different).

There are only a few sites where this is relevant so it's not going to clutter up the tags much, and simpler than getting somebody to understand that after adding an Ancestry tag then then need to go add a .com.au tag - very few would.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @RobHoare's suggestion. Site specific tags like [findmypast.co.uk](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/findmypast.co.uk) should be used when relevant, but I think [findmypast](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/findmypast) should also *always* be used. This will allow a user to either search for all questions regarding findmypast, or just questions regarding a specific site.

Comment: Are they really separate sites? I can go to yahoo.com or yahoo.co.in for instance and still login to my same account. If they all point to the same database, then the extra tags might be a bit overkill.