# How many FindMyPast tags are needed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

This question may be related to [Reviewing the subscription, website, and ancestry.com tags](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3189/reviewing-the-subscription-website-and-ancestry-com-tags) and [Should there be a tag for top level domains for web-based questions?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/should-there-be-a-tag-for-top-level-domains-for-web-based-questions) but I think it may be possible to achieve quicker and clearer consensus here than there by addressing a subset of what they try to cover.

We currently have two tags related to FindMyPast:

- [findmypast](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/findmypast) - 4 questions

> A suite of genealogy websites operated by brightsolid online
>   publishing across several national domains (including .com .co.uk
>   .com.au .ie). Use this tag when the question is applicable to several
>   of these.

- [findmypast.co.uk](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/findmypast.co.uk) - 4 questions

> One of a suite of genealogy websites operated by brightsolid online
>   publishing. Use this tag to distinguish questions peculiar to the UK
>   website of that name when it is necessary to distinguish it from those
>   in other domains (such as findmypast.com or findmypast.ie).

Do we need both, or perhaps more, FindMyPast tags?

Comment: With the only answer having 5 upvotes, and 0 downvotes, its proposal has been implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we need only one FindMyPast tag, with an updated tag wiki as indicated below (with my bolding to indicate the change):

- [findmypast](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/findmypast)

> A suite of genealogy websites operated by brightsolid online
>   publishing across several national domains (including .com, .co.uk,
>   .com.au, .ie). Use this tag when the question is applicable to **any**
>   of these.

The tag [findmypast.co.uk](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/findmypast.co.uk) should be made a synonym of the above.

If the actual FindMyPast domain name is important to the question then that should be written into the body of the question.

This is the same position that I took in [my answer](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2052/19) to [Should there be a tag for top level domains for web-based questions?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/should-there-be-a-tag-for-top-level-domains-for-web-based-questions)

Comment: I agree with one tag. Whether that is "findmypast" or "findmypast.com" is up for debate (the ".com" clarifying that it refers to a website, which may be convenient for "ancestry"). Add a country tag to the post if that's specifically relevant, rather than needing an extra "findmypast.wherever" tag for every country where FMP has a presence.

Comment: @AndyW I think the `.com` is valuable for Ancestry since questions about ancestry may not always be about the Ancestry websites.  However, I think FindMyPast and the combined FindMyPast websites are coextensive so I think there is no need for any further qualification.

Comment: true, I don't think that ".com" is necessary for other sites such as FMP, but if it's used for Ancestry then perhaps it should be used for other sites, simply for consistency.

Comment: @AndyW the same comes up where we currently have [tag:familysearch.org] as a tag. For now let's focus on whether only one tag is needed. Synonymizing and reversing synonyms is easy with mod tools. Getting consensus to use them is the hard part.

Comment: The proposal here has now been implemented.